# Is it possible to put damaged item variants on armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I would like to add custom armor into my resource pack, but I don't know how. I know about damaged item variants (and have used it a lot!), but is it possible to do it on armor? Feel free to go technical.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/resource-packs/resource-pack-help/2525365-how-do-you-attach-textures-to-items-with-damage?comment=4) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180430111438/https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/resource-packs/resource-pack-help/2525365-how-do-you-attach-textures-to-items-with-damage)) Minecraft forum user "Momlob" said:

> As far as I know you could do the Items from the Armor, there is no possible Way known to me to do it with the Armor shown on the Player.
> This is because the Model of the Armor unlike the Items and Blocks is not included in the model folder of a Resource Pack.

I have verified this with [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_pack#Folder_structure) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Resource_pack&oldid=1199729)): There is a resource pack folder for item models and one for block models, but none for armor. And since armor items uses textures that are not automatically generated from the worn armor, the texture and model is separate.

So I'm afraid, but currently (1.12) it seems to be impossible to change armor models. And since different textures for all the damage values are part of the model, that's also not possible for armor.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the armor texture, but adding custom armor needs modding the game. You can use Photoshop or Paint.net to create the textures yourself, and also you can grab people's texture and add it to your pack.

Comment: I think he means having a different armor texture for e.g. iron armor with durability 10.